# Is there a proper way to store Connection String in App.xml in WPF?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, visual-studio-2008, connection-string

Like define in XAML file?

I seen couples of example they were on define in code and stores into App.xmal, but I am just thinking when people look at the setting, they will look into App.xaml, not the code-behind.

i.e [this](http://syntaxhelp.com/WPF/sore-connectionstring-in-app.xaml) and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/e5ae2b18-0795-49e8-a274-c3d52eccb8b3)

And another thing is, I don't want to declares some property on code-behind, some in xaml, some in project property, it made things hard to find.

Is there proper place or way to stores the connection string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*App.config*. It is rather nonsensical storing this in a UI-specific XAML file.

Comment: Unless he wants it secure. In which case encrypting the string in app.config or storing in an XML file and embedding as resource might be a better option :)

Comment: @KentBoogaart Oh, I can store in App.Config? I thought I had to use App.xaml or project property.  I will try google how to do it.

Comment: @Dr. Andrew Burnett-Thompson I guess that's nice idea, I will keep that in mind. thanks :)